# lightning:input customError in ValidityState

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightninginput

I'm looking at creating a file importer in lightning, and with the restrictions on file size I'm trying to create an error message to display when the file is over 1mB.  If I log the `ValidityState` of the `<lightning:input type="file" ... />` to the console I get this:

```
ValidityState {
    badInput:false
    customError:false
    patternMismatch:false
    rangeOverflow:false
    rangeUnderflow:false
    stepMismatch:false
    tooLong:false
    tooShort:false
    typeMismatch:false
    valid:true
    valueMissing:false
}
```

The second line of the ValidityState references a `customerError` is there any way to define the function that sets the `customError` state?

Comment: I don't think there is a way. I tried a few things to set it, no dice.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right, `ValidityState` has `setCustomValidity()` but it looks like it's inaccessible :(

Answer (score 1):

## Summary

`ValidityState.customError` is true if you call `setCustomValidity(String: message)` on your field.

### Example:

#### Component

```
<lightning:input type="text" onchange="{!c.doCheckForm}" />
```

#### Controller

```
    {
        doCheckDateTo: function(component, event, handler) {
            var inputField = event.getSource();
            var value = inputField.get('v.value');

            if(value === 'Hi Joe!') {
                //inputField.get('v.validity') // valid = true, customError = false
                inputField.setCustomValidity('Text have to be "Hi Joe!"'); // Make field invalid
                //inputField.get('v.validity') // valid = false, customError = true
            } else {
                inputField.setCustomValidity(''); // Make field valid
            }

            inputField.reportValidity(); // Show Error on field
        }
    }
```

### Useful tip

You can also abuse attributes on input field as shown below. So, you don't have to keep message in controller.

```
<lightning:input type="text" onchange="..." messageWhenBadInput="Some error message" />

inputField.get('v.messageWhenBadInput'); // "Some error message"
```

Hope it helps...